# Number of solutions in non-negative integers question (Stars and bars)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Q How many solutions are there in non-negative integers $a, b
, c, d$ to the equation:

$$ a + b + c + d = 79 $$

with the restrictions that $a \geq 10$, $b \leq 40$ and $20 \leq c \leq 30?$

If anyone could point me to any notes regarding the topic that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$$x_1=a-10\quad \quad,\quad x_2=b,\quad x_3=c-20\quad,\quad x_2=d$$
we have
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=49 \quad ,\quad x_1\ge0\,\,\,\, , \quad 0\le x_2\le 40\quad  ,\quad 0\le x_3\le10\,\,,\quad x_4\ge0$$
Now apply inclusion and exclusion principle
[image]
$$\operatorname{n}(S)-\operatorname{n}(A)-\operatorname{n}(B)+\operatorname{n}(A\cap B)$$

**1**. let $x_2\ge41$ we have
$$n(A)=C\left( \begin{matrix}
   8+4-1  \\
   3  \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$$

**2**. let $x_3\ge11$ we have
$$n(B)=C\left( \begin{matrix}
   38+4-1  \\
   3  \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$$

**3**. let $x_2\ge41$ and $x_3\ge11$ we have
$$n(A\cap B)=0$$
finally
$$C\left( \begin{matrix}
   52  \\
   3  \\
\end{matrix} \right)-C\left( \begin{matrix}
   11  \\
   3  \\
\end{matrix} \right)-C\left( \begin{matrix}
   41  \\
   3  \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$$

Comment: The number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 49$ in the *positive* integers is $$\binom{48}{3} = \frac{48!}{3!45!}$$ since a solution corresponds to placing three addition signs in the $49 - 1 = 48$ spaces between successive ones in a row of $49$ ones. However, what we want here is the number of solutions in the *non-negative* integers.  A solution in the non-negative integers corresponds to placing three addition signs in a row of $49$ ones.

Comment: The number of solutions to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 49$ in the non-negative integers is $$\binom{49 + 3}{3} = \binom{52}{3}$$  To see why, observe that if we instead had the equation $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 = 10 \tag{1}$, a particular solution corresponds to the placement of three addition signs in a row of ten ones.  For instance, $$1 1 + + 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1$$ corresponds to the solution $y_1 = 2$, $y_2 = 0$, $y_3 = 5$, and $y_4 = 3$.  The number of solutions of equation 1 is $$\binom{10 + 3}{3} = \binom{13}{3}$$ since we must choose which three of the $13$ symbols are $+$ signs.

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki A nice way of doing it. I'm kind of confused as to how you left out the x1 by minusing 10 off of a?

Comment: @Trigamatuer because $a\ge 10$ whereas we should have $a\ge 0$  therefore $a\to  a-10$

Answer (score 1):

Using generating functions, we want to find the coefficient of $x^{79}$ in the product

$\displaystyle(x^{10}+x^{11}+x^{12}+\cdots)(1+x+\cdots+x^{40})(x^{20}+x^{21}+\cdots+x^{30})(1+x+x^2+\cdots)$

$\displaystyle=\left(\frac{x^{10}}{1-x}\right)\left(\frac{1-x^{41}}{1-x}\right)\left( x^{20}\cdot\frac{1-x^{11}}{1-x}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=x^{30}\cdot\frac{(1-x^{41})(1-x^{11})}{(1-x)^4}$.

Therefore we need to find the coefficient of $x^{49}$ in

$\displaystyle\left(1-x^{11}-x^{41}+x^{52}\right)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+3}{3}x^n$, which is given by$\displaystyle\binom{52}{3}-\binom{41}{3}-\binom{11}{3}$